Wittgenstein and formal relations

We can speak in a certain sense of formal properties of objects and atomic facts, or of properties of the structure of facts, and in the same sense of formal relations and relations of structures.
(Instead of property of the structure I also say “internal property”; instead of relation of structures “internal relation”.
I introduce these expressions in order to show the reason for the confusion, very widespread among philosophers, between internal relations and proper (external) relations.)
The holding of such internal properties and relations cannot, however, be asserted by propositions, but it shows itself in the propositions, which present the facts and treat of the objects in question.

Wittgenstein, TLP, 4.122
What are formal relations between objects? Can you give me an example? I must've missed something, I guess.

That is what SparkNotes are for:"An example of a concept proper is "x is a horse"; an example of a formal concept is "x is a number." We cannot say that x is a number: that it is a number shows itself. Any attempt to use a formal concept in a proposition (e.g. "two is a number," "purple is a color") will result in a nonsensical pseudo-proposition (4.1272)."

See 4.014 "A gramophone record, the musical idea, the written notes, and the sound-waves, all stand to one another in the same internal relation of depicting that holds between language and the world."
So, the internal relation between symbols and the objects they stand for is a condition on representation.
We may apply a form-matter dichotomy; see 2.0233 "If two objects have the same logical form, the only distinction between them, apart from their external properties, is that they are different."
Thus, "external" properties are the matter of which the symbols are made, while the "internal" ones are the formal properties that must be shared by different objects/facts in order to make representation possible.

+1 The OP might keep in mind the message and medium distinction. The letter G can be painted, printed, or carved into a surface, but what constitutes the letter G, that is, when is something a G or not, is a different dimension of variation. Consider linguistics and the notion of the allograph.
